# What is the Enable lock screen notification in my Micromax a064

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings, notifications, lock-screens, lock-screen-widgets

I have a Micromax Bolt A064 smartphone running on android 4.4.2. I know that KitKat have the option to enable lock screen widget in security. My phone doesn't support it. But that's not the problem. When I go to Settings->Display, I find an unknown option labeled as lock screen notification. So, my final question is what is it?. I tried to enable and disable it and see the changes but nothing changed.

Also, sliding from left to right have nothing. Anyone here just know what is it. I am attaching a screenshot for that.

[image: The screenshot. Settings>display>lock-screen notifications]

<sub>Screenshot (Click to enlarge image)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Lock screen notifications are only available since Android 5.0 (Lollipop).
However you can use 3rd party apps - such as "[NiLS - Lock screen notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roymam.android.notificationswidget)" from Google Play to be able to get notifications on top of your stock lock screen without replacing your lock screen app.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling it must show notifications like messages, missed call events, mails or whatever, directly on the lock screen itself. Tapping or swiping on them must take you to the specific app or just dismiss the notification right on. For all this to work you need to use lock screen feature first (only the stock one).  If its not working as it should you may repair the software using the company provided PC software like PC suite or something or reset the phone once after everything is backed-up.

Comment: How it should work? If you have any screenshot of that? It would be very helpful. And also, on what type of lock screen, slide,pattern,pin or password? Thanks for answering my question but please add some details.

Comment: I don't have any screenshots because my phone doesn't support that. Because it's a stock lock screen it must work on all kind of password techniques. You may check out CM Lockscreen or Microsoft's NEXT lock screen apps to know what Lockscreen notifications are.

Comment: But that would be a difficult task. I've use go locker and other lockers. The notification are shown after my concern but on my default lock screen i.e the stock lock-screen, no notifications are shown even after enabling the above option.